# Cannot download InceptionV3 Keras

Tags: python, keras

When I try downloading the InceptionV3 model with weights

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
from keras.models import save_model

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
save_model = (base_model, 'inceptionv3_base.h5')
```

I get the below error :

```
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Incomplete or corrupted file detected. The auto file hash does not match the provided value of bcbd6486424b2319ff4ef7d526e38f63.
```

I have already tried upgrading my keras and TF libraries and it did not work

Comment: Does the error also show on Google Colab?

Answer (score 0):

On Google Colab there are no errors with your code:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
from keras.models import save_model

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
save_model = (base_model, 'inceptionv3_base.h5')

import tensorflow
import keras

print(tensorflow.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)
```

Output:

```
2.12.0
2.12.0
```

Try using version `2.12.0` for both `tensorflow` and `keras` and improving the reliability of your internet connection and hard-drive.